# SecurityKit problem, snow leopard

Tags: cocoa, security, osx-snow-leopard, code-signing

Very simple question but I can't seem to get it to work.

Imagine the following code, why would the compiler give me the errors below? I've imported the relevant header file, included the framework. Target is 10.6.

```
#import <Security/Security.h>


- (void) snowLeopardCodeSignCheck
{
    SecStaticCodeRef ref = NULL;
}  



'SecStaticCodeRef' undeclared (first use in this function)  

error: expected ';' before 'ref'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Security.h doesn't include any of the headers that would lead to CSCommon.h being included. You need to include `<Security/SecStaticCode.h>`.

You may want to [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) about this.